# Preserving text when converting from .dxf to .shp?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dxf

I have tried using dxf2shp converter in QGIS but the text in dxf file is being lost during the conversion process, despite selecting export text labels.

How do I convert the .dxf to .shp file without losing data?

Comment: Is it possible to visualize original angles of text?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a case that you want to load it into Qgis and display the lables just do it that way there is no need to put as shapefile.

Sorry on further reflection and looking at the data.  Why not load as dxf and split vector layer. load them in as shapes then.

I seem to get most text come through.

Or perhaps split the layers in autocad and save as seperate dxfs. I think you problem is when you try dxf to shp it only allows for polygons polylines or points not all 3. you have polyline/gons and points. so put points on seperate layer.

Of course if you have split dxf into shapes then convert polygon to points.

you may want to merge shapefiles to one at the end but dont see the point as there will be issues.

Answer (score 2):

Opening the dxf with `Add Vector layer` and labelling with `text` datafield gives almost the same as Autodesk Design Review:

[image]

[image]

The DXF file contains points and polygons in the same layer. This is not allowed in shapefiles. That is why you can not save it as a shapefile.

Exporting as kml will work, as this format supports different geometry types.
You have to set `NameField=Text` in the `Data Source` Field to preserve the text into the Name field for labelling.

---

EDIT

You can export the data as lines shapefile, and ignore the error messages. In a second run, you can export the labelling points by adding `SHPT=POINTS` in the `Layer` field, ignoring again the error messages. Load both shapefiles into QGIS manually, label the point file with the `Text` field, and set the point symbol to zero size.

Answer (score 0):

i tried with QGIS 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x86_64) with dxf plugin and only a single attribute is getting copied to shapefile. From the attribute data of converted shapefile it seems like dxf converter plugin just adding a new attribute field `myid` to every feature rather than copying data from source dataset. It will be good to inform QGIS developers may be submit a bug on [QGIS issue tracking](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues)